# Form Not Submitting on Click

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add a "Create" to one of my Controllers (`LeagueController`), so I created a `Create` View, which uses my `League` object.

However, when I go to submit the form, it does not redirect back to the `Index` view, as I want it to, nor does it enter the log entry to say that I created a league.

`League` Class

```
public class League : BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LeagueName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LeagueInitials { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string LeagueURL { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime Founded { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("League")]
    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LeagueID")]
    public ICollection<LeagueOwners> LeagueOwners { get; set; }
}
```

`LeaguesController` Class

```
public class LeaguesController : Controller
{
    private MyDBContext context;
    private ILogger logger;

    public LeaguesController(MyDBContext context, ILogger logger)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("Reached League Index");
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Create")]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("Creating a league");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Create(League league)
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("Create button clicked!");
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

`Create.cshtml`

```
@model MySite.Core.Entities.League

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>League</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LeagueName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LeagueName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LeagueName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LeagueInitials" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LeagueInitials" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LeagueInitials" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LeagueURL" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LeagueURL" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LeagueURL" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Founded" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Founded" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Founded" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" hidden="hidden">
                <label asp-for="Created" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Created" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Created" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" hidden="hidden">
                <label asp-for="Modified" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Modified" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Modified" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it hitting the function? Did you tried putting a break point? Also look for CSRF cookies and form values since it is an HTTP POST.

Comment: Please mention Http GET also on
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        this.logger.LogInformation("Creating a league");
        return View();
    }

also route on post Action..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is that you could delete `[Route("Create")]`which is on your get method.

The second way is that you could add `[Route]` attribute to your post method like below:

```
[Route("Create")]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    this.logger.LogInformation("Creating a league");
    return View();
}
[Route("Create")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(League league)
{
    this.logger.LogInformation("Create button clicked!");
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wound up adding the routing directly. It just seems a.) cleaner and b.) way easier to follow

Answer (score 1):

In your form `<form asp-action="Create" method="post">` add a tag to point to the correct controller `asp-controller="Leagues"`

Do not enforce the route, that's just anti-pattern.